# can not get the cordova-sms-plugin to work

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to install a [cordova sms](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms) plugin. and I'm doing like te following steps:

1. created a new project by `phonegap create smsProj`
2. added android platform by `phonegap platform add android`
3. installed the plugin by `cordova plugin add com.jsmobile.plugins.sms`
4. then I tried to check if `SMS` is available by:

```
try {
  alert( SMS == undefined );
} catch (e) {
  alert('catch: SMS is not available')
}
```

I'm checking this after `deviceReady` event, in *Android*, *latest cordova* and of course by building and installing in **real device**. but I'm getting the catch alert every time. 
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this line into your `config.xml` file:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.rjfun.cordova.sms" source="npm"/>
```

this configuration must be added programmatically since you've installed the plugin using `CLI`, but in this case it's not what I expected. I figured it out opening the `apk` file content and checking cordova plugins JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin object is `sms` , not `SMS`.